# PHP create_function, function without semicolon?

Tags: php, function, create-function

basically, what i want to know is, for the second parameter in the create_function function, is there anyway to pass a string without a semicolon? or will it not work.

example:

```
taken from php.net
create_function('$a,$b', 'return "CRCs: " . crc32($a) . " , ".crc32(b);'),
```

notice that there is a semicolon in the string. is there any possible way someone can enter a function without a semicolon that will still run/evaluate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. PHP is semicolon-sensitive, that you must use it to terminate every statements before right braces. I even tried regular function like this:

```
function f() {
  return 1
}
```

and it spitted out a syntax error, unlike in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

With create_function() you're creating an anonymous function. The second parameter is a string that is the code of the function (like any other function you'd write). It doesn't have to end in a semicolon, for example:

```
$coolfunction = create_function('$thing', 'if ($thing > 0) {return "Yes"; } else { return "no!"; }');

echo $coolfunction(1) . ' and ' . $coolfunction(-1);
```

Ends in a '}' and prints out: Yes and no!

Comment: It doesnt have to end it one, but it must contain atleast one right? Otherwise no possible valid PHP could be created?

Answer (score 0):

You should always sanitize any user input before using it.
I suggest that you look for the semicolon in the user input, if it is missing, append it.

If the user can enter anything here you still have a problem if he enters an invalid function name or just rubbish.

You can validate with [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) (although I'm not an expert on preg so I will let someone else help you out there).

Answer (score -3):

First, why do you need that ? That's a really dirty way to create a function. Hope because you want to make a interface where people can directly create a function (and this will be only for you or it'll be a big security issue). I don't really get how you want to use that.

Anyway, for you question, you don't have to care if it's working or not. I mean, just test if it's working, if not just put by yourself a semicolon. It's just a simply test on a string.

Comment: If you read my question properly, you would have figured out that I wanted to know if anyone could construct that part without a semicolon. Not that a semicolon has to be at the end of the string

Comment: If you read my answer properly you will notice that I never say that the semicolon has to be at the end of the line... Still try it by yourself...